# Replace function dont work with brackets ()

Tags: javascript, replace, brackets

I stuck for a while on a replace function. basically it works, but it does not work with brackets `()`.

I have prepared a fiddle for that:

[jsfiddle.net/99xPY/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/99xPY/3/)

Markup:

```
<span>Textarea / Longtest</span><br>
<input id="textarea_1" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" value="12()1212">

<br><br><br>

<span>String to replace</span><br>
<input id="textarea_2" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"><br>

<span>Replacing String</span><br>
<input id="textarea_3" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30">

<input type="button" value="execute" onclick="replace()">
```

Javascript:

```
function replace(){
    var longtext = document.getElementById('textarea_1').value
    var StringToReplace = document.getElementById('textarea_2').value
    var UserReplacingString = document.getElementById('textarea_3').value;
    var oldWordRegEx = new RegExp(StringToReplace,'g');
    var result = longtext.replace(oldWordRegEx,UserReplacingString);

    alert(result);    
}
```

So enter `1` in the second box and a random value in third box. My JavaScript code replaces automatically all `1's` in the first box, but it does not replace `(` or `)`.

Can somebody help me with this problem please?

I have to use pure JavaScript (`OnClick`) and not jQuery or similar.

Answer (score 2):

`(` and `)` are special characters for a Regex. You need to escape them. Your code used with `\(\)` instead works.

Answer (score 2):

Some characters have special meaning in regular expressions, so you must escape them.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400316/1529630), you must escape the characters `.^$*+?()[{\|`.

To escape, add `\` before them, but note you must also escape `\` inside a string, so you need `\\`:

```
StringToReplace.replace(/[.^$*+?()[{\|]/g, '\\$&');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/99xPY/6/)

Comment: @user3482484 See the edited answer, the escaping method I first proposed wasn't correct.